# Is there an autocomplete feature for folder and file names in bash?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I need to navigate to a certain directory and then execute a script located there.

I am using `cd folder_name` to navigate to the next directory.

One folder has a very long name (with white spaces). Is there a way to type only the first few letters and then use a shortcut key to autocomplete with the first matching name, or to navigate through possible matches?

The same if I want to perform a command on a certain file (e.g. `chmod XXX file_name`), is there a way to get the name to appear after I type a few letters of the filename?

The shell I am using is bash-3.2 in OS X 10.7.4.

Comment: did you try pressing TAB? (and press TAB twice to get a full list)

Comment: By the way, you can learn this by typing "bash autocomplete" into Google. Much easier than asking a question here.

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thank you! I was pressing tab before, but my case wasn't matching. The name of the folder was in uppercase.

When I searched Google for an answer it gave me more advanced completion features (for commands and scripts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Bash supports auto-completion (personally, it's one of my favorite features). Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to complete what you've typed (note that it's case-sensitive). The Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide has a section on [an introduction to programmable completion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html). You can enable completion to complete command names and more!